# formatting events date and time on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Supposing am getting the dates for an event from a database in what format should my event date be am thinking.

start: 2012-03-29, 08:00am, 
end: 2012-03-30, 08:00am,
allday: false,

it does not recognize the end date and the time for the event

Am I doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following format and it works for me:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt
e.g.
03/15/2012 05:10 AM
```

Also make sure that in your JSon you have allDay as a boolean and not as a string

```
"allDay"= "false", // this is wrong. In this case you won't see any events on your calendar

"allDay"= false,   // This is correct
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it worked well! Do you know the format for repeating an event?

Comment: As far as I know FullCalendar doesn't support repeating events. I am currently working on it. But in case of repeating events most of the logic will be in Server Side code. You have to design your DB table and your Server Side code to best support the repeating events.
If you need more details about logic, let me know.

Comment: My events aren't showing with any internet explorer browser, but they work perfectly with other browsers. please help, i know you have the answers. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Daniel Barde Please share your JSON with me. Also I suggest you to create a new question for this so, more people can participate.