# Fullcalendar agenda view and Day event doesnt render events within specific time ( hours )

Tags: fullcalendar, renderer, dayofweek

I'm using Fullcalendar from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ , i have search stackoverflow but no answear fits my problem, or i didnt understood. Please paste links if this was already answear.

I have a xml file that returns events:

Event example:

```
<event allDay="false" editable="true" end="Mon Apr 29 2013 15:30:00 GMT+0100" id="53" start="Mon Apr 29 2013 08:30:00 GMT+0100" title="tesete"/>
```

if you notice the start and end day, the time format was saved like this.

When i fetch the events like so:

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType:'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                      
                    'ajax':true,
                    'acc':'2',                      
                },
                success: function(doc) {                            
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {
                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            allDay: $(this).attr('allDay'),
                            editable: $(this).attr('editable')
                        });                             
                    });                                     
                    callback(events);
                }
            });     
        },
```

All events show up in the month view correctly, but when i switch to agendaView or dayView, the events are only in the allDay bar, they are not rendered between the specific hour.

```
 start="Mon Apr 29 2013 08:30:00 GMT+0100" end="Mon Apr 29 2013 15:30:00 GMT+0100" id="53"
```

From 8:30 to 15:30 for example

What am i missing?

SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM:

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myurl',
                dataType:'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),                      
                    'ajax':true,
                    'acc':'2',                      
                },
                success: function(doc) {                            
                    var events = [];
                    var allday = null; //Workaround 
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() 
                    {               

                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "false") //Workaround 
                                allday = false; //Workaround 
                        if($(this).attr('allDay') == "true") //Workaround 
                                allday = true; //Workaround                         

                        events.push({
                            id: $(this).attr('id'),
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start'),
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),                       
                            allDay: allday,
                            editable: $(this).attr('editable')
                        });                             
                    });                                     
                    callback(events);
                }
            });     
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var allDay must not be a string. It should be `allDay=false` without the quotes

Comment: Yes but this is an event in a xml file so the attributes value must be in the quotes to actually be a value.

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT MY FRIEND THANK YOU :), sorry for being dumm :)

This was actually awnseared here also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933373/formatting-events-date-and-time-on-fullcalender